# How to protect object losing in git for using as a content addressable fs

Tags: git

Here I make a database system which uses the **git** as a content addressable filesystem. In the **git** repository, we only use low level command for adding blob objects, and then we will save the file name in a database.

In this **git**, there is not any commit, tree objects. So we want to check whether the `git gc` may remove these unreachable blob objects?

Is there any way to protect losing unreachable objects? The `git config --global gc.auto 0` is a good way for doing these? After closing gc, the pack feature will work or not?

Comment: Why are you using GIT in such manner? Pushing blobs into it and NOT using their references anywhere has no point, at least I can't see any point. You'd get better using simple network share and dropping files/directories/etc. As far as my knowledge spans, in such setup GIT will gives you absolutely nothing. OTOH, if you create some 'repo' and 'tree' and have the files really referenced/versioned - that's what SCMs are for - keeping history. Anyways, answering the question - I think that GC will swipe all unreferenced/unreachable things. So yes, you'd need to turn it off. But then, it'd be OFF.

Comment: So if keep in that git also other files/things, they would NOT be cleaned up, ever, and your repo would just grow and grow full of trash, unless you manage that manually too. This is an option (everythign except GC would work normally), but I wouldn't go that way. I'm not writing this as an answer, deliberately. I'm not sure if I'm 100% right. I didn't ever try to use Git this way so I may be wrong about the GC. But, hell, that's the point of GC: remove unreachable things..

Comment: @quetzalcoatl thanks for your suggestion. Here we use ``git`` protocol for file sharing: uploading and downloading. We will create a commit for a special request and then the user can download only this reference without downloading too many files. Because of using **git**, we don't have to rewrite packing, breakpoints downloading and use gerrit for authoring. :-)